laravel css not applying styles when called from public folder
I'm new to laravel but I'm having a hard time applying css.
Here's what I did:

I have a parent blade file called main.blade.php - this will call the component with generic classes

component file called weather.blade.php - this has generic class names, no css whatsoever

css file in public/css/weather.css - using external file that way dev can freely customize


Note: I can see the css file and when I copy paste it in the browser. but when inspecting the element I can't see the styles being applied.
When I try to copy paste the contents of the css file into main.blade.php directly it works fine
So in main.blade.php:
<x-partial-layouts>
@push('styles')
<link href="{{ asset('css/weather.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
@endpush

@push('styles')
...
@endpush

<x-weather>
...
</x-weather>
</x-partial-layouts>

